# Perl WWW:Mechanize not connecting over https

Tags: perl, https, mechanize, www-mechanize

I am trying to connect to a https website with WWW:Mechanize.  When I run my script, I receive the error "Network is unreachable..." message shown below.

Why is it using http.pm and not https.pm which is present in that directory?  Source and error below...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use WWW::Mechanize;

$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
print "WWW::Mechanize: ", $WWW::Mechanize::VERSION, "\n";
print "LWP : ", $LWP::UserAgent::VERSION, "\n";
print "LWP::Protocol::https : " , $LWP::Protocol::https::VERSION, "\n";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->protocols_allowed(['https']);
$mech->add_handler("request_send", sub { shift->dump; return });
$mech->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });

my $url ="https://www.cpan.org";

$mech->get( $url );

my @links = $mech->links();
for my $link ( @links ) {
    printf "%s, %s\n", $link->text, $link->url;
}
```

Output:

```
WWW::Mechanize: 1.75
LWP : 6.13
LWP::Protocol::https : 6.06
GET https://www.cpan.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: WWW-Mechanize/1.75

(no content)
500 Can't connect to www.cpan.org:443
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 03:29:49 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to www.cpan.org:443\n
Network is unreachable at /home/coldsoda/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 47.\n
Error GETing https://www.cpan.org: Can't connect to www.cpan.org:443 at ./mechurl.pl line 24.
```

Comment: I am unable to connect to `https://www.cpan.org` using `https` through browser but able to connect to `https://metacpan.org/` this using your script. I guess CPAN doesn't support `https`.

Answer (score 0):

> my $url ="https://www.cpan.org";

Rule #1 when having problems with a script reaching a site: check with the browser. Surprise: it fails in the browser with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Which tells you that the site is not available with the browser too, so why should it work with the script.

> Why is it using http.pm and not https.pm which is present in that directory?

Because https is just http inside an SSL tunnel https support in LWP makes heavy use of the http support. Thus you get the error message from http.pm.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried multiple sites to test http v https and the presence of the http.pm question clouded my thinking.